# Dependency Management of npm packages

Tags: azure-devops, azure-artifacts

Is there anything like greenkeeper.io or dependabot.com for VSTS?  These solutions will look into the package.json file, compare the current project's version of a dependency against the most recent published version, and propose PR's that are incrementing the dependency to the latest version.

Comment: Maven works with VSTS these days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn’t such feature in VSTS.

The workaround:

1. Create a Scheduled build definition for specified repository and branch
2. Add the task to check version and update version (e.g. PowerShell call npm outdated command and analysis the result, then call npm update command to update package)
3. Add Command Line task to call git commit command to commit changes
4. Add Command Line task to call git push command to push changes
5. Add PowerShell task to call REST API to create a [pull request](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/pull-requests/pull-requests#create-a-pull-request) (Invoke-RestMethod)

Answer (score 0):

NPM itself has that ability. For example, you can use `npm outdated` command [as described here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/outdated).

Comment: Looking for the continual scanning and automated pull request creation.

Comment: cannot you incorporate the command into your chain with something like a bash, npm run-script, webpack etc?

Answer (score 0):

I'm fashionably late to this question, but I think it's worth a clearer and more up-to-date response. Yes Renovate is available out there  and it is the best tool for managing your depndency updates. It works well with VSTS and npm along other package manager like nuget, maven, gradle and other source control like gitlab and github and self-hosted gitlab.

check the following link for further information:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jyc.vsts-extensions-renovate-me